# browserHistory not Moving to New Component in React

Tags: reactjs, authentication, components, browser-history

I have this strange authentication issue with react.

When a user logins, the `authentication prop` is set to true. If a user tries to go into a route and authentication is undefined or false then I push them back to the login page.

Currently it looks like this:

PersonId Component

```
  componentWillMount() {
    console.log("MOUNTING PERSON ID COMPONENT IF AUTHENTICATED IS TRUE", this.props.authenticated)
    if (!this.props.authenticated) {
        browserHistory.push("/login");     
      }
    }


 render() {    
    if(this.props.user.type == "Admin")
```

The problem is, even when `this.props.authenticated` = undefined, and even when the browser history pushes the component to the login route, the render method for the `PersonId` component still plays.

This does not make sense. If I push a component to another route why is it still rendering the PersonId component?

Comment: instead of `push` use, `replace` try this: `browserHistory.replace('/');`

Comment: I tried that and unfortunately it does not work :/

Comment: I don't know if you can omit rendering component after executing componentWillMount. I always just add some guard condition in my render method like `if(!this.props.authenticated) { return null; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are using should work, you can do one more thing, put the same check inside `render` also, and `return null`, it will not `render` anything, like this:

```
render() { 
      if (!this.props.authenticated) {
          return null;
      }
      ....
}
```

Comment: This extra step seemed to have done the trick! For some reason my component still renders even if it's pushed. But since its set to null, no errors show up. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
componentWillMount() {
    console.log("MOUNTING PERSON ID COMPONENT IF AUTHENTICATED IS TRUE", this.props.authenticated)
    if (!this.props.authenticated) {
         browserHistory.push("/login");     
         return; 
    }
}
```

Try this will work. Component will still render because you have not break if loop.

Comment: My route changes to login but the render for PersonId is still running. The loop still runs but wasn't broken. :(

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to wrap all private components in a HOC (higher order component) something like this:

```
  export default function CheckForAuth(Component) {
            return (
                class PrivateComponent extends React.component{
                    constructor() {
                        this.state = {
                            isAuthed: false
                        }
                    }
                    componentDidMount() {
                        //if user is authenticated set isAuthed to true
                    }

                    redner() {
                        let rednerThis;
                        if(this.state.isAuthed) {
                            rednerThis = <Component {...this.props} />
                        }
                        return (
                            <div>
                                {rednerThis}
                            </div>
                        )
                    }
                }
            )
    }
```

What you have here is a function that takes a react component as an argument. It then returns a newly created class that has a boolean on state that is set to true or false depending on you checking if the user is authenticated. If `isAuthed`, then render the component that was passed in as an argument, otherwise redirect to your login page.

This will give you the same functionality you are after, but with code for checking the user's authentication only once. As opposed to your current set up where each component is checking for authentication twice. Once in the willmount, and again in the render.